# Selenium with Chrome driver taking screenshots at double resolution on retina display

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, retina-display

I am using [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/) with [Chrome driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/) to taking some website screenshots. I need the screenshots to be at very specific resolution (`1024x768`). I've noticed that although the browser is correctly set at this resolution, the screenshot on disk is saved at double resolution (`2048x1536`). I suspect this is due the retina resolution of the macbook where I am running the application (mid 2017 macbook pro).
This is the code I am using:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

width = 1024
height = 768

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--lang=en')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument(f'window-size={width}x{height}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://google.com'
driver.get(url)
print('Window size', driver.get_window_size())  # Window size {'width': 1024, 'height': 768}

driver.save_screenshot('test.png')  # Image is saved at 2048x1536
```

Is there a way to prevent the screenshot to be taken at double resolution on retina?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found a possible solution:

```py
chrome_options.add_argument('--force-device-scale-factor=1')
```

Comment: This would be helpful to a lot of questions.

Comment: thanks, it worked for me in C#: options.AddArgument("--force-device-scale-factor=1");

Comment: I found a bug where sometimes it does not use the default device scale factor of 2. Setting it fixed the bug.